# How do I configure netplan in Ubuntu 22.04 with dynamic IPv4 and static IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, netplan, ubuntu-22.04

With Ubuntu 22.04, the `gateway` option is deprecated and nearly every example I find for configuring `netplan` with static IPv6 uses `gateway`.

My ISP's default `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` only includes dynamic IPv4 and they do not provide DHCP support for IPv6, but they do provide support for static IPv6.

What do I add to the configuration to support IPv6?

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
```

I should also add that my ISP also does not provide nameserver support for IPv6 but they do provide an IPv6 address and a gateway IPv6 address.

Gateway IPv6 address:

```
2001:DB8:6404::1
```

Instance IPv6 address:

```
2001:DB8:6404:10fB:928a:b151:d721:51bc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added to the configuration the `dhcp6`, `addresses`, `nameservers`, and `routes` to `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` and it has been working so far:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 2001:DB8:6404:10fB:928a:b151:d721:51bc/48
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 2606:4700:4700::1111
          - 2606:4700:4700::1001
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: ::/0
          via: 2001:DB8:6404::1
```

The `nameservers` in the above configuration are for Cloudflare. Feel free to change them to something else.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all - Please take a backup of the file 01-netcfg.yaml**.

To configure IPv6, you would need to configure the file `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

From your above code, I have assumed the interface server is using **eth0**

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - IPv6-Address/IPv6-Netmask
      nameservers:        
        addresses:
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
      routes:
          - on-link: true
            to: default
            via: IPv6-Gateway
```

Replace **IPv6-Address/IPv6-Netmask** & **IPv6-Address/IPv6-Netmask** with your ISP provided values.

Save the file & to apply the configurations using

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot now
```

For Nameservers, I have used Google's Public DNS

1. 2001:4860:4860::8888
2. 2001:4860:4860::8844

You can also use Cloudflares DNS

1. 2606:4700:4700::1111
2. 2606:4700:4700::1001

In case after reboot the Internet Connection does not work properly in your system, Just revert the file `01-netcfg.yaml` & use `sudo netplan apply` & `sudo reboot now`